# How to call a function upon http get or post?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, asynchronous

I'm sure this is a stupid question but I am very new to the backend so please forgive me.

I am building an angularjs app with express/node also and am trying to integrate PayPal (as a [Node.js SDK](https://github.com/Ideame/paypal-adaptive-sdk-nodejs)), what I want is to call the pay method on the SDK from an angular controller and I am doing as follows:

On button click:

```
// controller
$scope.pay = function(amount) {
  PaymentFactory.doPayment(amount);
}
```

Payment Factory:

```
// PaymentFactory
return {
    doPayment: function(amount) {
        $http.get("../../../server/payments/paypal.js")
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log( response );
            })
    }
}
```

Then the server-side file is as below:

```
require('paypal-adaptive');
var app = require('../../server.js');
var PayPal = require('paypal-adaptive');

var paypalSdk = new PayPal({
    userId:    'userid',
    password:  'password',
    signature: 'signature',
    sandbox:   true //defaults to false 
});

var payload = {
    requestEnvelope: {
        errorLanguage:  'en_US'
    },
    actionType:     'PAY_PRIMARY',
    currencyCode:   'GBP',
    feesPayer:      'EACHRECEIVER',
    memo:           'Chained payment example',
    cancelUrl:      'returnUrl,
    returnUrl:      'cancelUrl',
    receiverList: {
        receiver: [
            {
                email:  'email1',
                amount: '3.40',
                primary:'true'
            },
            {
                email:  'email2',
                amount: '1.20',
                primary:'false'
            }
        ]
    }
};

paypalSdk.pay(payload, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // Response will have the original Paypal API response 

        // But also a paymentApprovalUrl, so you can redirect the sender to checkout easily 
        console.log('Redirect to %s', response.paymentApprovalUrl);

        return response;
    }
});
```

Of course the get request just returns a string of the server-side file contents, I understand why the above doesn't work but not sure how one would make it work. My aim is to call the PayPal SDK from the angular factory and get back the response so that I can redirect a user to a URL. A direct solution would be helpful but even more so I need pointers to the principles that I am not understanding here as far as how one should call functions upon user actions to get this data from the server side. I have tried searching but I don't really the language to use in my search.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use curl (node-curl npm module). Using curl will help you post data to your paypal url and get back the response. Now you need to handle this response from paypal and accordingly generate your own response to be received by the angular http method.